# How do I disable multiple button colour selection on ScrollView Items?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, uiscrollview

I'm working on a photo editor mobile app that let's the user click on a item inside the scrollview to display the larger image above it.

The problem is when I tap on multiple items it keeps displaying the same blue colour.

What I'm looking to do is disable multiple selections so only one colour is displayed at a time on each item in the scrollview.

Here's the function that I've been working in:

```
func ScrollFunctions() {


    var xCoord: CGFloat = 13
    let yCoord: CGFloat = 7
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 60
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 60
    let gapBetweenButtons: CGFloat = 5


    var itemCount = 0

    for i in 0..<CIFilterNames.count {
        itemCount = i

        // Button properties

        let filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        filterButton.frame = CGRect(xCoord, yCoord, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)
        filterButton.tag = itemCount
        filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LooksViewController.filterButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        filterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        filterButton.clipsToBounds = true

        // Create filters for each button

        currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "\(CIFilterNames[i])" )
        let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
        let coreImage = CIImage(image: imagePassed)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "\(CIFilterNames[i])" )
        filter!.setDefaults()
        filter!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let filteredImageData = filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
        let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)
        let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!);
        // Assign filtered image to the button
        filterButton.setBackgroundImage(imageForButton, for: .normal)


        // Add Buttons in the Scroll View
        xCoord +=  buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons
        filtersScrollView.addSubview(filterButton)
    }

    // Resize Scroll View
    filtersScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(buttonWidth * CGFloat(itemCount+2), yCoord)

}
```

here's the function when you tap a scrollview item. Inside here I've been experimenting with 'if else' statements like if the button is selection display the border width and color, else return false but this hasn't worked. Any ideas?

```
@objc func filterButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let button = sender as UIButton
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2
    button.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1882352941, green: 0.6392156863, blue: 0.6705882353, alpha: 1)
    imgView.image = imagePassed
    toolBar.isHidden = true
    yesAndNoToolBar.isHidden = false
    imgView.image = button.backgroundImage(for: UIControlState.normal)

}
```

Comment: your question is not clear ? what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to make it so the 'button.layer.borderColor' and 'button.layer.borderWidth' is only enabled on one uiscrollview item at a time.

Comment: please place screenshot for expected output.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aGOCe2suaPouSlZSH242Iwjsqu68PojU

Comment: This is what I want to happen when I select each item in the uiscrollview. It just has one item selected at a time

Comment: This is what is currently happening after you have selected at least one. It keeps highlighting blue on the other items. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fbADNbcJEMVDPgGR2t8Gx-dwlpk7DYHb

Comment: So I just want it to highlight blue on one item at a time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, you can take one member variable like below.

```
var lastSelectedButton: UIButton?
```

Now in `filterButtonTapped(sender: UIButton)`function check the lastSelectedButton

```
let button = sender as UIButton
if let button1 = lastSelectedButton {
// Deselect or reset this button1 color.
} 
lastSelectedButton = button
// Do your stuff here what you are doing now.
```

If any doubt plz comment.